# Are strings from a list present in a column?

Tags: r

The first column of my dataframe (FOOTNOTES) contains footnotes.

I created lists of strings to identify their type, for example:

```
law <- c("Directive", "Commission Decision", "TFEU", 
"TEU", "OJ L", "OJ C", "Case C-", "CJEU", "Council Decision", 
"Official Journal", "(EU)", "(EEC)", "legal basis", 
"Commission Regulation", "Article", "Regulation", "(EC)", 
"Legislative framework", "Treaty", "Resolution", "Convention", 
"Judgement of", "Ordinance", "Decision", "Paris Agreement", 
"Law", "Art.", "legislation", "Charter of", "AGRILEG", "REACH")
```

When trying to find each word individually using `str_detect` it works. However, I would like to be able to ask if any of the element of the list is present to print "TRUE" in a new column (called LAW)

It is not working using regex ("|" between the strings). I receive no error message BUT I checked manually and I actually get TRUE everywhere although the strings in the list are not present in the FOOTNOTES.

I tried creating a new column for each word of the list individually but then I am not able to export the dataframe in the excel format. My idea was to filter the columns LAW --> LAW12 to merge the responses into just 1 column but I cannot find a way to do that either.

I think the first idea would go faster but I am out of ideas on how to implement it.

```
DATABASA_V6$LAW <- str_detect(DATABASE_V6$FOOTNOTES,"[Directive|Decision|TFEU|OJ L]") 

DATABASA_V6$LAW <- str_detect(DATABASE_V6$FOOTNOTES, "OJ L")
DATABASE_V6$LAW1 <- str_detect(DATABASE_V6$FOOTNOTES, "Regulation")
DATABASE_V6$LAW2 <- str_detect(DATABASE_V6$FOOTNOTES, "Directive")
DATABASE_V6$LAW3 <- str_detect(DATABASE_V6$FOOTNOTES, "TFEU")
DATABASE_V6$LAW4 <- str_detect(DATABASE_V6$FOOTNOTES, "TEU")
DATABASE_V6$LAW5 <- str_detect(DATABASE_V6$FOOTNOTES, "Legal basis")                              
DATABASE_V6$LAW6 <- str_detect(DATABASE_V6$FOOTNOTES, "Official Journal")
DATABASE_V6$LAW7 <- str_detect(DATABASE_V6$FOOTNOTES, "Case C-")
DATABASE_V6$LAW8 <- str_detect(DATABASE_V6$FOOTNOTES, "Decision")
DATABASE_V6$LAW9 <- str_detect(DATABASE_V6$FOOTNOTES, "Resolution")
DATABASE_V6$LAW10 <- str_detect(DATABASE_V6$FOOTNOTES, "Article")
DATABASE_V6$LAW11 <- str_detect(DATABASE_V6$FOOTNOTES, "Treaty")
DATABASE_V6$LAW12 <- str_detect(DATABASE_V6$FOOTNOTES, "Convention")
```

When trying to identify if any word of the list is present in the column footnotes, I expect to receive arount 2000 TRUE out of 14,000 rows.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give a small [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) along with expected output.

Comment: As joran started, brackets (`[`) are used to define a character class, not a set of possible strings. That is, `[ab|cd]` matches exactly one of `a`, `b`, the literal `|`, `c`, or `d`. Parens, however, provide choices: `(ab|cd)` matches one of `ab` or `cd`.

Answer (score 0):

You have most of the solution already. As Joran and r2evans explained above, you don't want square brackets. You can also format your list of strings for regex in one step using `paste(law, collapse = "|")`.

```
law <- c("Directive", "Commission Decision", "TFEU", 
         "TEU", "OJ L", "OJ C", "Case C-", "CJEU", "Council Decision", 
         "Official Journal", "(EU)", "(EEC)", "legal basis", 
         "Commission Regulation", "Article", "Regulation", "(EC)", 
         "Legislative framework", "Treaty", "Resolution", "Convention", 
         "Judgement of", "Ordinance", "Decision", "Paris Agreement", 
         "Law", "Art.", "legislation", "Charter of", "AGRILEG", "REACH")

law_formatted <- paste0(law, collapse = "|")

tst <- data.frame(footnote = c("footnote footnote OJ L footnote footnote", 
                               "blah blah (EU) blah", 
                               "nothing to see here",
                               "words words. words words words Art."))
tst$law <- stringr::str_detect(tst$footnote, law_formatted)
```